# How to use Custom App Insight Metric in VMSS AutoScale Rule on Azure?

Tags: azure

Im trying to create scale rule for my VMs with command

```
az monitor autoscale rule create --resource-group MyGroup --resource "cc-insight" --resource-type "Microsoft.Insights/components" --autoscale-name autoscale --condition "cc-response-time-view > 2000 avg 5m" --scale out 1
```

But getting

```
Exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.MonitoringServiceException' was thrown.. [Code: "UnsupportedMetric"]
```

While metric is accessible from App Insights

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A bit of manual testing and i solve this problem.

Here is Terraform config for rule with custom metric that works. Keep in mind that all custom metrics names starts with **"customMetrics/you-metric-name"**

```
rule {
      metric_trigger {
        metric_name        = "customMetrics/cc-response-time-view"
        metric_resource_id = azurerm_application_insights.insight.id
        time_grain         = "PT1M"
        statistic          = "Average"
        time_window        = "PT5M"
        time_aggregation   = "Average"
        operator           = "LessThan"
        threshold          = 1500
      }

      scale_action {
        direction = "Decrease"
        type      = "ChangeCount"
        value     = "1"
        cooldown  = "PT1M"
      }
    }
```

For those who use console don't forget to set namespace to **"microsoft.insights/components/kusto"**